# JavaFX changes new Scene to Caspian stylesheet

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, jvm

I got two scenes coded using FXML. Both are defined as using the 'Modena' theme.

When launching my first scene from the first fxml file, the style matches what I've defined, however, when I start a new scene it sets the theme to the older 'Caspian'.

I am using Eclipse, compiling with JDK7.

How do I keep the 'Modena' theme universal?

Snapshots from the theme-switch:

Modena
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPwuR.png

Caspian
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqEen.png

Comment: Code
Main.java http://pastebin.com/syiYhYmg
MyController.java http://pastebin.com/ubPD2s7f

FXTest.fxml http://pastebin.com/gDnq17T4
MainMenu.fxml http://pastebin.com/rAdwjePV

Comment: What version are you running under? Those themes look the same to me (I think they're actually both Caspian). What do you mean when you say the FXML is defined using the "Modena" theme?

Comment: I was compiling with JDK7. Turns out this limits the theme options to Caspian. Updated Eclipse and JDK8 which now displays the new Modena theme. (The old ones were both indeed pictures of the Caspian theme)

Comment: You can compile with Java 7, but if you run with Java 8 it will use Modena by default